# Trying to salvage a messed up dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, data-cleaning

I've been tasked with the tedious job of salvaging a mangled dataset that looks like this in its .txt file form

```
 "DATE"|"ID"|"TITLE"|"NAME"|"SURNAME"|"INCOME"|"ADDRESS1"|"JOB"
||MR|ROBIN|WILLIAMS|291029102|
2019-01-01||MRS||DREW||SECOND_TO_THE_RIGHT_AND_STRAIGHT_ON_TILL_MORNING||
2021-02-04|||JONATHAN|SIMMONS|3012000|SOMEWHERE_IN_BEVERLY_HILLS|
|MARK|ZUCKERBURG||SILICON_VALLEY|
|||PARKER|JONES||SOMEWHERE_IN_HIS_HOMETOWN_IN_
NORTHERN_ITALY
2019-06-03|4444301243451|MRS|CARMEN|SANDIEGO||WHERE_IN_THE_WORLD_IS_
CARMEN_SANDIEGO|THIEF
2018-02-25|2395022812223|MR|ARNOLD|SCHWARZENEGGER|MUSCLE_BEACH_VENI
CE_CALIFORNIA_USA|ACTOR
|DOCTOR|STRANGE|NEW_YORK_SA
NCTUM|SORCERER_SUPREME
||HAL|JORDAN||EARTH|GREEN_LANTERN
2019-01-02|0212931229475|MR|KEVIN|BACON|129340212|SOME_PLACE_IN_THE_US|ACTOR
2019-01-03|2939583749642|MRS|NICOLE|KIDMAN|291928494|BEVERLY_HILLS|ACTOR
2019-03-15|2947959371923|MR|WARREN|BUFFET|2000000000|OMAHA_NEBRASKA|INVESTOR
2020-02-45|2847939172394|MRS|JULIE|ARIS|200034|SOMEWHERE_IN_THE_UK|LECTURER
```

There are two major problems with this dataset that I've been struggling with, the first of which is that there aren't enough delimiters in certain rows (e.g. the first row) and the second being that long values in the address column have somehow caused the address value to "spill over" into the next row. When I asked the people in charge of extracting the data from their databases why the data looked like this, this was apparently caused by people pressing "Enter" while inputting long addresses, which also meant that the data was stored this way in the database to begin with, thus ruling out any possibility of a re-extraction rectifying these errors. According to them, the easiest way to rectify the second problem is to press backspace at the head of each problematic row like this.

```
 "DATE"|"ID"|"TITLE"|"NAME"|"SURNAME"|"INCOME"|"ADDRESS1"|"JOB"
||MR|ROBIN|WILLIAMS|291029102|
2019-01-01||MRS||DREW||SECOND_TO_THE_RIGHT_AND_STRAIGHT_ON_TILL_MORNING||
2021-02-04|||JONATHAN|SIMMONS|3012000|SOMEWHERE_IN_BEVERLY_HILLS|
|MARK|ZUCKERBURG||SILICON_VALLEY|
2019-01-02|0212931229475|MR|KEVIN|BACON|129340212|SOME_PLACE_IN_THE_US|ACTOR
2019-01-03|2939583749642|MRS|NICOLE|KIDMAN|291928494|BEVERLY_HILLS|ACTOR
2019-03-15|2947959371923|MR|WARREN|BUFFET|2000000000|OMAHA_NEBRASKA|INVESTOR
2020-02-45|2847939172394|MRS|JULIE|ARIS|200034|SOMEWHERE_IN_THE_UK|LECTURER
```

While technically not a bad solution, I'm not about to do this manually for a dataset that has over 2 million rows.

My first idea was to look for escape characters in the datafile using Notepad++, but there were no signs of escape characters in the dataset at all. My second idea was to try to read the datafile row by row and append it to a dataframe using the following lines of code.

```
import time
start = time.time()

with open("DATAFILE.txt", 'rt', encoding = 'UTF8') as f:
    data = f.read()

fl = data.splitlines()

# 350231 rows
len(fl)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, 10000):
    df1 = df1.append([fl[i+1].split('|')], ignore_index=True)
print('Total Time:',round((time.time() - start),2), '(sec)')
```

This did absolutely nothing as it gave me the exact same results as read_csv, which is why I'd very much appreciate some advice on how to solve this problem.

Example of a row with empty values filled in with NaN:

```
"DATE"|"ID"|"TITLE"|"NAME"|"SURNAME"|"INCOME"|"ADDRESS1"|"JOB"
NaN |NaN|MR|ROBIN|WILLIAMS|291029102|NaN
```

Note that this row is also missing a delimiter for the JOB column

Comment: Should every row end with `|`?

Comment: maybe provide more rows as it difficult to see a pattern as it is. should every row starts with MS or MRS for instance?

Comment: @AndrejKesely My bad for not making it clearer in the original post. The rows are not supposed to end with a pipe. Null values in this dataset are represented by an empty field; the first row would look something like the example that I've added to original post if null values were added in place of the empty space (the example row is also missing a delimiter for the "JOB" column).I've updated the original post to add a few more examples, including examples of correct rows.

Comment: @NonoLondon Thanks for dropping in NonoLondon, I've added a few more examples to the original post

Comment: @DanielCoben Thanks for updating the question. Can you please post "not-updated" example of file (like the first example you have, but with more lines - so we can have something to work with)

Comment: @AndrejKesely I've updated the original post to include some more rows. Thanks for the help AndrejKesely!